# new azure webrole doesnt show references to objects

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure

I really hope you can help as i used a lot of time figuring out what is wrong. I moved my website from a regular asp.net project to a azure webrole (copy and pasted all the classes).

The site works just fine but i realized that a lot of typechecking is missing. You can see on the following image that it doesnt regonize the classes:
[image: error]

For example doesn't intellisense work and if i CTRL+Click (VS productivity tools) it says "Cannot navigate to 'DataClassesDataContext'.

As seen on the picture i tried creating some new object of an unexisting class (new JustSomeRandomStuffIMadeUp()). This error doesnt show up before the webserver is actually running.

How do i get Visual-studio to recognize the classes again?

Thank you
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click one of your class files that isn't being picked up and select 'properties', is the *Build Action* set to 'Compile' as shown below?

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I also messed up some parts of the namespace when copied but now it works!